# Getting 404 error while call oAuth2 api in the browser

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, doorkeeper

I used ruby on rails to make RESTful api and also used doorkeeper to handle authentication and authorization. As you know the doorkeeper generate some OAuth2 api's and the two of the them that i need to use is /users which is the post request and /oauth/token that make token for me. The api that i make which are post, get, put works greate in postman and android studio and web browser.
But the post api /users and /oauth/token which generated by the doorkeeper doesn't work in web browser but works great on android studio and postman.
That was confused for me. The error that i take while calling this api is 404, I checked the ruby production log on the server and it says no route match. The string thing here is that the type of method and routes is correct.

This is the code that i used in the reactjs. i used axios:

```
var url="http://x.x.x.x/oauth/token";
    axios.post(url,{
        "username":"1",
        "password":"password",
        "grant_type":"password"
      },{headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"}}).then( (response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch( (error) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
```

And also used raw jQuery to make request and get the same error. all my api works well execpt this two api:

```
var firstname = document.forms["registerForm"]["first_name"].value;
    var lastname = document.forms["registerForm"]["last_name"].value;
    var pass = document.forms["registerForm"]["password"].value;
    var passconfirm = document.forms["registerForm"]["password_confirmation"].value;


    var json_data = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": send,
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json",
        },
        "processData": false,
        "data":
        {
            "user": {
                "user_name": username,
                "password": pass,
                "password_confirmation": passconfirm,
                "user_type": "admin"
            },
            "profile": {
                "first_name": firstname,
                "last_name": lastname
            }
        }
    }

    $.ajax(json_data).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
    console.log(json_data['data']);
    console.log(username);
```

the output of this code console.log(JSON.stringify(error)); is this:

```
{"config":{"transformRequest":{},"transformResponse":{},"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"},"method":"post","url":"http://x.x.x.x/oauth/token.json","data":"{\"username\":\"1\",\"password\":\"password\",\"grant_type\":\"password\"}"},"request":{}}
```

I find the request header and response header into the browser:

```
Response Header:

Content-Type    
application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length  
34
Connection  
keep-alive
Status  
404 Not Found
X-Request-Id    
d593b73f-eec8-41cd-95cd-e4459663358c
X-Runtime   
0.002108
Date    
Mon, 13 Nov 2017 11:19:26 GMT
X-Powered-By    
Phusion Passenger 5.1.11
Server  
nginx/1.12.1 + Phusion Passenger 5.1.11


Request headers (427 B) 
Host    
x.x.x.x
User-Agent  
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linu…) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0
Accept  
text/html,application/xhtml+xm…plication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method   
POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers  
Origin  
http://localhost:3000
Connection  
keep-alive
```

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: This could be related to CORS, can you try using var `url="http://x.x.x.x/oauth/token.json"` ?

Comment: yes i just added json to end of my endpoint but it doesn't worked and also did this tutorial about CORS like this https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html and added to my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is because of CORS policy. You can [rack-cores](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors).
It is a rack middleware and you will be able to make cross domain requests to your doorkeeper protected application

Answer (score 2):

After checking their [docs](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/API-endpoint-descriptions-and-examples#post---oauthtoken), it looks like you need to change `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and data as `key=value` pair:

`const data = 'username=1&password=password&grant_type=password'`

or simply:

```
const formData = {
  username: '1',
  password: 'password', 
  grant_type: 'password',
}

const data = Object.keys(formData)
  .map(prop => `${prop}=${formData[prop]}`)
  .join('&')
```

Final result would be:

```
var url="http://x.x.x.x/oauth/token";

axios.post(url, data, {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  }
}).then( (response) => {
  console.log(response.data);
})
.catch( (error) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Comment: I tested your ways but doesn't work out and i get a  response in WWW-Authenticate which says Bearer realm="Doorkeeper", error="invalid_request", error_description="The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported parameter value, or is otherwise malformed."

Comment: @Sandro their docs also mentions to send (`grant_type`, `client_id`, `client_secret`, `code`.. ) are you sending those props?

Comment: The trick is const data = Object.keys(formData)
  .map(prop => `${prop}=${formData[prop]}`)
  .join('&')

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure in your OAuth settings to allow access to client web app. Check logs or error message which you get in api response.

Comment: @Sandro have you found any solution yet ?

Comment: No, Im still searching, one of the senoir developer said that it can be from call back url in doorkeeper but I don't know how to configure call back url in doorkeeper. In doorkeeper there is some theorical text about call back but there is no technical document about it.dont really know what to do

Answer (score 0):

```
    function login(username, password, returnUrl) {

    const formData = {
        grant_type:"password",
        client_id:"xxxxxxxx",
        client_secret: "xxxxxxxxx",
        redirect_uri:"xxxxxxxx.com/api/v1/accounts/profile/",
        username:username,
        password:password
    }

    const d = Object.keys(formData)
      .map(prop => `${prop}=${formData[prop]}`)
      .join('&')

    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            'Accept': 'application/json'
         },
        body: d
    };

    return fetch('xxx.com/o/token/', requestOptions)
        .then(handlePostResponse)
        .then(token => {

            // login successful if there's a user in the response
            if (token) {
                token.token = token
            }

            console.log(token)

            return token;
        });

}
```